Try signing in with a different account.....google auth problem after deployment on vercel
Running the google authentication project on localhost, it works perfectly along with the database updation as required. When deployed on vercel along with the replacement of url, redirect url with the vercel link in google console and adding the env varibales as well during the deployment, it shows the error of try signing in with different account.
I tried to make changes in google console approprialty and revising the .evn file again and again but nothing happened.
